# loss of precision when using pandas to read excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, precision

I tried to use pandas to read an excel sheet into a dataframe but for floating point columns, the data is read incorrectly. I use the function read_excel() to do the task

In excel, the value is 225789.479905466 while in the dataframe, the value is 225789.47990546614 which creates discrepancy for me to import data from excel to database.

Does anyone face the same issue with pandas.read_exel(). I have no issue reading a csv to dataframe.

Jeremy

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Do you have the same issue when exporting to csv (with Excel) then using read_csv?

Comment: actually I just checked in more detailed, if I use read_csv, I face the same issue as well, some of my cells have precision up to 8 or 9 numbers

Comment: How about if you export to CSV and then look in the CSV file to see what numbers are there? It could just be that Excel isn't displaying the full precision on the screen when you look at it.

Comment: as I said above, loading using read_csv gives me the same issue for number with a lot of floating points

Comment: @JeremyNguyen Andy's asking you to use Excel to export a CSV file and then compare the CSV to excel manually.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is just floating point error and/or the default Excel view not showing you the full precision of the number.

Also consider the following:

```
from decimal import Decimal
x = Decimal(225789.479905466)
y = Decimal(225789.47990546614)  
print(abs(x - y)/y)
6.444904002816901933512563658E-16
```

So is a 6.5e-14% discrepancy going to meaningfully change the outcomes of your analysis?

I'd wager that it will not.

Comment: the file stores money amount hence I need it to be exact though

Comment: @JeremyNguyen then floating point precision on computers is the wrong way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Excel might be truncating your values, not pandas. If you export to .csv from Excel and are careful about how you do it, you should then be able to read with `pandas.read_csv` and maintain all of your data. `pandas.read_csv` also has an undocumented `float_precision` kwarg, that might be useful, or not useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the function lambda x : float( '{:n}'.format( x ) ) to remove the floating point error, or at least correct how the floating point is displayed.

For more information, see [link1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and [link2](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues).

```
def fix_float_error(x): return float('{:n}'.format(x))
```