# Converting Excel Sheets into Separate CSV files keeping all decimals

Tags: python, python-3.x

I looked at this post (among many other posts): [splitting an Excel workbook into multiple excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60402180/splitting-an-excel-workbook-into-multiple-excel-files) which is helpful for creating individual files from different sheets in one Excel workbook, but I need to retain all the decimals of the numbers.

The end goal is to convert the data on each sheet in the Excel workbook into individual csv files. The purpose of having them in csv files is to prevent rounding issues in calculating float values. The rounding issues make a difference because the dollar amounts being calculated are very high and high precision is required. Any libraries used need to be compatible on a linux server.

How do I accomplish this? Is there another way to go about this?

I could manually save the data on each tab in a new workbook as a csv which prevents rounding issues, but I'd like to automate it.

Comment: csv files do not preserve formatting. they are data-characters only.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "rounding issues"? If you mean floating-point errors, then those will remain regardless of the file format because they are inherent to the way numbers are represented as floats. If you're talking about Excel's GUI rounding off some numbers, that's a formatting issue that has nothing to do with the file format. Excel still keeps the number to the precision that was input, but can display more or less decimals depending on the formatting you select

Comment: Yes, floating point errors. As an example, when I do a pivot table in pandas, the sum is different than a pivot table in excel, unless I import the data from a csv. Is there another way to approach this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37492173/loss-of-precision-when-using-pandas-to-read-excel